# SQL Server New or Existing for a Sharepoint Installation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

We have a Sharepoint farm that uses a SQL Server. I need to create another Sharepoint farm. Can i reuse the same SQL Server or do i need a new one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same SQL Server (capacity planning issues aside), but obviously with different database names.